# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe called `total` which contains several columns. the columns `NUTS level` contains 4 unique values:

```
    NUTS level NUTS code  ...         2016        20172
2        Other       UK0  ...   1,093,785    1,111,703 
3        NUTS1       UKC  ...      41,145       41,811 
4        NUTS2      UKC1  ...      18,154       18,491 
5        NUTS3     UKC11  ...       4,457        4,569 
6        NUTS3     UKC12  ...       4,092        4,137
```

I am trying to obtain all rows in the dataframe that ave the string `NUTS1` in and have tried to from the following code:

```
new_df = total[total['NUTS level'].str.contains('NUTS1')]
```

However I receive the following error:

`TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

All the responses seem to suggest a problem in numpy but I am not using numpy?
Can anyone explain please. Thanks

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use ```total.loc[total['NUTS level'] == 'NUTS1', :]```

Comment: @EricTruett yes